# ¿Cómo capturar el response como un objeto en javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, response

tengo esta función y me genera un array con un token y un usuario en response pero no sé como obtenerlo:

```
$("#post_Respuesta").on("click", postRespuesta);


function postRespuesta(){
  const data = JSON.stringify({ 
    username: $('#usuario').val(),
        password: $('#contraseña').val(),

  }) 
  console.log(data);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://andresriascos.pw/api/v1/login',
    method: "post",
    contentType: 'application/json; charsat-utf-8',
    data: data,
    success: function(elemento){
      sessionStorage.setitem('tokeen',elemento.token);
      console.log(sessionStorage.getitem('tokeen'));

    }
  });}
```

¿Alguien me puede colaborar?

Answer (score 0):

Si es un arreglo con formato: `["token","usuario"];` puedes accederlo por su índice:

```
sessionStorage.setitem('tokeen',elemento[0]);
```